# escape single quotes

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this...

```
select * from myescape;
+-----------+
| name      |
+-----------+
| shantanu' |
| kumar's   |
+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to replace the single quote ' with \'

I will also need to escape double quotes and backslash.

Comment: You forgot to tell *why* you need to do this. Because chances are that you don't.

Comment: In a stored procedure, I am using prepare statement. The single quote is getting completed at the single quote found in the mysql data.

Comment: There is single and double quotes both in the column so I can not use any quote to complete the prepared statement.

Comment: Are you using php in your application or what? Becouse with php is way more easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this;

```
UPDATE myescape SET name = REPLACE(name, "'", "\\'");
```

You may want to think precisely about *why* you might want to do this (as Tomalak has said). Even in a stored procedure these fields should be strings, not commands.

Answer (score 19):

The point of prepared statements is that you don't have to include content in them. Use a `PREPARE` query with `?` placeholders and then `EXECUTE ... USING` to pass the values in without having to escape them.

Don't try to do escaping yourself, because you're likely to make mistakes. Depending on what encoding you're using, there can be more to it than just backslash-escaping quotes, backslash and null.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [char function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_quote).

```
mysql> SELECT QUOTE('Don\'t!');
        -> 'Don\'t!'
mysql> SELECT QUOTE(NULL);
```

Helpful link

- http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/How_do_I_escape_single_quotes_in_SQL_queries%3F
- http://www.webproworld.com/webmaster-forum/threads/61969-single-quote-in-mysql-record

Comment: Double quotes does not get handled using that.

Comment: And it is adding extra single quote 
SELECT ('Don\'t!');

Comment: @shantanuo, why do you think double quotes *need* to be escaped?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE( REPLACE( name , "'", "\\'" ) , '"', '\\"' )
FROM myescape
```